# CSS - How do I add a circle around an icon with a different color than the icon itself?

Tags: css, icons, background-color

I want the white to stay the same, with a circle background of another color. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/RT33aXz

I've tried using background-color: brown on the img in CSS but that just changes the whites in the icon to brown.
Also tried wrapping the img in a div and giving that div a different background color. But the same thing happens.

Any ideas?

This example just covers the entire whites of the phone icon to the brown color. Same thing happens when I try to change background color when wrapping the image in a div.

```css
img {
  height     : 30px;
  width      : 30px;
  background : rgba(109, 73, 59, 255);
}
```

```html
<img src="image/phone.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...

Comment: Added my code, hope it's enough.

Comment: This is just css. where is the svg icon ?

Comment: Edited again. Better? I'm just trying to grasp how to make a decent looking icon.

Comment: your PNG image is like a stencil, that's mean the "phone" color is transparency. you can only change the phone color, not the background

Comment: I see. So how would I go about making it look like the image I posted? Wrapping it in a div doesn't seem to work.

Comment: either you modify your image with an editor like GIMP, or you use a real SVG icon to allow you to change the colors as you wish in CSS.

Comment: Tried using a white .svg. Still the exact same problem.

Comment: SVG code doesn't use the same css syntax as HTML element. they use a SVG-CSS syntax. If you din't show this SVG code, I can't help

Comment: Haha, okay. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do it:
We are putting the image inside a rounded div.

```
<style>
    .circle {
        display: flex;
        /* CIRCLE SIZE */
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        background: red;
        /*BACKGROUND COLOR HERE*/
        border-radius: 50%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .circle>img {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* IMAGE SIZE */
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="image/phone.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I try this, the phone color changes to red. I need the background color to be red, and the phone itself all white! Like the image I posted.

Comment: send your full code, and if possible the image with, I can't see your image and what are you looking for exactly.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="circle">
        <img src="image/phone.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: CSS:

    .circle {
        display: flex;
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
        background: red;
        border-radius: 50%;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .circle>img {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }

the image im using: https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/telephone_159832?related_id=159832

I need the background in the circle to change color but the phone itself stay white.

Comment: ok, just use a different image witch is not transparent in the middle.
bacause here, if we modify the color of this png img, it will create a entire square BEHIND the png (as background).

Comment: I see! So how could I make a white phone icon with a brown background color? Like this: https://imgur.com/a/RT33aXz

Comment: like i have said, take a different image with a full "interior" (not transparent)
For example this image is good:
https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/phone-call_597177?term=phone&page=1&position=3&origin=tag&related_id=597177
With a tool like photoshop, you can change the phone color with the color you want !